# Attempting to get the last row from a Google Forms submission into a new sheet row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to grab the last row from a form responses sheet within Google Sheet and paste the value from column C to an existing sheet cell.

```html
function MovieAdditions() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1snk4-M9nKBLZLTMs81xn8Tt2Q8AeSoDj4eWOjWlVOeg').getSheetByName('Form Responses 2');
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var sourceData = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 2, 1, 5).getValues();
  //Insert new row within spreadsheet for data from Form responses
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Movie List'), true);
  Logger.log(sourceData[0][0]);
  Logger.log(sourceData[0][1]);
  Logger.log(sourceData[0][2]);
  Logger.log(sourceData[0][3]);
  Logger.log(sourceData[0][4]);
  spreadsheet.getRange(sourceData).copyTo(spreadsheet.setActiveRange('\'Movie List\'!B3'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

I am able to return the range data I am looking for if I change to a static range reference within the sheet, I can confirm that via logger I am getting the value I am looking for back but when actually running the script in the current configuration I get back an error that the range is not found.

```html
7:09:34 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:09:35 AM  Info    P2
7:09:35 AM  Info    Ant-Man and the Wasp Quantumania
7:09:35 AM  Info    2023.0
7:09:35 AM  Info    4K Ultra HD
7:09:35 AM  Info    Digital
7:09:36 AM  Error   
Exception: Range not found
MovieAdditions  @ NewMovieAddition.gs:22
```

If I use the below I can return the desired values.

```html
spreadsheet.getRange('\'Form Responses 2\'!B8:C8').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(),     SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
```

My potential "fix" option is to just user a static row on the form responses sheet and it just copy and past the last row to the static row which I can use to be the rerence on the other sheet. But I would prefer to have it work without that workaround.

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Use onFormSubmit trigger e.range.rowStart is the current row being  written to

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in this line of code.
`spreadsheet.getRange(sourceData).copyTo(spreadsheet.setActiveRange('\'Movie List\'!B3'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);`

But there are several syntax issues.

Try this revised function...

---

```
function MovieAdditions() {
  // assumes that the bound container is a spreadsheet contain the "Movies List" sheet
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var movies = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Movie List")
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1snk4-M9nKBLZLTMs81xn8Tt2Q8AeSoDj4eWOjWlVOeg').getSheetByName('Form Responses 2');
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 2, 1, 5)
  var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
  
  //Insert new row within spreadsheet for data from Form responses
  
  Logger.log(sourceData[0][0]);
  Logger.log(sourceData[0][1]);
  Logger.log(sourceData[0][2]);
  Logger.log(sourceData[0][3]);
  Logger.log(sourceData[0][4]);
  
  sheet.getRange(sourceRange).copyTo(movies.getRange("B3"));
};
```

---

- `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` -  this line only defines the active **spreadsheet**. So you need something to define a sheet
- `var movies = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Movie List")` - this line defines a specific sheet on the active spreadsheet.
- `var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 2, 1, 5)`
- `var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues()`

  - `copyTo` requires a range, so you may as well define the range AND the values.
- `sheet.getRange(sourceRange).copyTo(movies.getRange("B3"));`

  - `getRange` is a "sheets" method; so "spreadsheet" will fail
  - `getRange` requires a cell range, but `sourceData` was not a range.
  - `copyTo` - there are several options but the most simple is to simply provide a "destination range to copy to; only the top-left cell position is relevant."